# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, string

I have got a problem with my PHP, I'm trying to convert the hours into format, example: I have the time of 9:00 PM and I'm converting them to format 20140501210000.

When I try to convert the time into format, I'm getting the warning which it expects parameter 2 to be string. The error are jumping on this line: `$ex = explode(" ",$string);`

Here is the input for the time:

```
9:00 PM 9:30 PM 9:00 PM 9:00 PM 9:00 PM 9:00 PM 9:30 PM
```

Here is the errors I have got:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 8

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 8

Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 78
19700101010000


Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 8

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 8

Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/myusername/public_html/work_on_this.php on line 78
19700101010000
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';

$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
//@$domdoc->loadHTMLFile($baseUrl);
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$i = 0;
$count = 0;

$data = array();
foreach($links as $link)
{  
  //echo $domdoc->saveXML($link);
  if($link->getAttribute('href'))
  {
     if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || $link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
     {
       $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       //echo $url;
       //echo "<br>";
       $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
       $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $sdoc->recover=true;
       @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
       $time1_span = $sdoc->getElementById('time1');       
       //$spans = $sdoc->getElementsByTagName('time1');
       $query = parse_url($url)['query'];
       $channel_split = explode("&", $query)[0];
       $channel = urldecode(explode("=",$channel_split)[1]);
       $id_split = explode("&", $query)[1];
       $my_id = urldecode(explode("=",$id_split)[1]);
       $xpath = new DOMXpath($sdoc);
       $time1 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time1']");
       //$time2 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time2']");
       //$time3 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time3']");
       //$time4 = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time4']");

       $array = array(
         $time1,
       );

       // Save the output format
       $DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

       // GET the current STAGE
       $current_state = getState($array[0]);
       $offset = 0;
       $flag = 0;

       foreach($array as $time)
       {
         // Get the item state.  
         $this_state = getState($time);

         // check if we past a day? 
         if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM")
         {
           $offset++;
         }
         $this_unix = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
         $values[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
         //echo date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
         echo $values[0];
         echo "<br></br>";
         $current_state = $this_state;
         $count++;
       }
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Do you know why I'm getting the warning errors and do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `explode()` requires a **string** as its second parameter. You're currently passing an object. Locate all `getState` function calls and `var_dump()` the parameter. If it isn't a string, figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this_state = getState($time);
```

At this point, `$time` is `$xpath->query("*/span[@id='time1']");`

An XPath query returns a node list. An object. i.e. not a string.

Did you maybe mean this?

```
$this_state = getState($time->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made the change. When I try the code you suggest me to use, I'm still getting the same warning. Any idea?

Comment: You may need to do this in other places too. Just pay more attention to the items you are working with.

Comment: sorry, I have forgot to remove the `,` in the $array. I have removed the errors. So how I can print the strings using with the $array?

Comment: any idea how i can print the $array?